# Isolate scope requires templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is an incredible simple app:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div parent ng-repeat="parent in parents">
      <h1>{{ parent.family }} Family</h1>

      <div child="parent.child">
        Their kid's name is {{ child }}
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

With the following `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.parents = [{
      'child' : 'John',
      'family': 'Johnson'
    }, {
      'child' : 'Jack',
      'family': 'Jackson'
    }, {
      'child' : 'Jeff',
      'family': 'Jefferson'
    }];
});


app.directive('parent', function()
{
    return {
      restrict: 'AE'
    }
});

app.directive('child', function()
{
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        child: '='
      }
    }
});
```

I'm expecting to see three rows that says "Jackson Family. Their kid's name is Jack" and so on. This however doesn't work because of the isolate scope on `child`. Instead, If I change the markup to

```
<div parent ng-repeat="parent in parents">
  <h1>{{ parent.family }} Family</h1>

  <div child="parent.child"></div>
</div>
```

and then add an extra line to `child` directive that says `template: 'Their kid\'s name is {{ child }}'`, then it works.

Here is the plunker for the two scenarios:

1. [FAULTY plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1L3SntVo3aU3vkujsiMD?)
2. [WORKING plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNkkbPpamqTRDIWCdpHB)

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without extra work, you can either use the `transclude` option in your directive, so that the contents are bound to the parent scope, but then the contents would need to be:

```
Their kid's name is {{ parent.child }}
```

Or, you can isolate the scope (as you did), but then the scope would need to be applied to the template defined in the directive - which you don't want to do.

**EDIT:**

The `$compile`-approach below (as originally written) is sub-optimal, since it would make the contents compile and link twice. The proper (and better) approach is to use `transclude`:

```
app.directive('child', function($compile)
{
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        child: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
          transclude(scope, function(clone){
             elem.append(clone);
          });
      }
    }
});
```

modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Pq0VWsxoxTjE4YWGwSI?p=preview)

`transclude` compiles the contents once when the `child` directive is compiled, but makes the compiled content available. By invoking the `transclude` function, you can link the contents against the specified scope - here, the scope of the child directive.

**Original answer (not recommended)**

To make your example work - which is to use the contents of the directive as the template - you need to $compile them with the directive's scope, like so:

```
app.directive('child', function($compile)
{
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        child: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem){
          $compile(elem.contents())(scope));
      }
    }
});
```

Here's your modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mt5KDdUUWw7xcyfKqHk2).

Answer (score 0):

In second scenario you passing when you've got

```
 <div child="parent.child"></div>
```

you passing parent.child to directive using two way binding

```
scope: {
        child: '='
      },
```

so you can use child in your template

```
template: 'Their kid\'s name is {{ child }}'
```

in first scenario (faulty) you tring to reander child

```
Their kid's name is {{ child }}
```

but child not exist you can fix that by changing that to

```
 Their kid's name is {{ parent.child }}
```

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/V4ds0YHjGboQUlR3vzy6?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I know I can say `{{ parent.child }}`. What I meant though say that I want to isolate the scopes, but I don't want to use a template or a templateUrl to move the isolates scope's HTML to another page. Why can't I do this? Why does the template of the isolate scope has to be injected by the directive itself?

Comment: This might help https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Comment: @Kousha ok, so for what reason do you want create directive ?

Comment: in your example you have a directive which has an isolated scope but isn't doing anything.  Just creating a directive doesn't isolate the HTML contained within the element.  It only isolates the HTML generated by the directive, either through direct javascript manipulation or through templates.  the directive on the `<div>` does not change the scope accessibility for the child elements of that `<div>`